# Simplest possible SystemJS setup with ES6 features

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, systemjs

I am getting increasingly frustrated with trying to do really simple things with javascript. I find terms to be vaguely described and require existing insight into the javascript ecosystem.

I am trying to create a really basic setup to start developing a javascript app using ES6 features and specifically import and export functionality. I have looked for hours for a sample project with the most basic setup needed for this but have come up empty. So here goes.

Pre-requisites:

- I want to use NPM
- I would like to use SystemJS as my module loader as I have used this in the past with Angular

Questions:

If I have an index.html and a system.config.js file and have run "npm install systemjs --save", how do I proceed to only get the module loader to work AND add support for basic ES6 features, including import and export?

Can I use babel-polyfill and what does babel-polyfill actually do in this context?

Am I correct in assuming that babel-polyfill is all I should need from BabelJS?

Can anyone help with a sample or could provide help with configuration of my index.html file and system.config.js file?

I currently have this system.config.js file:

```html
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Thank you!